# Event MouseUp is not valid on this ActiveX control

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, data-structures, activex

This is an extremely frustrating problem that seemed to come out of nowhere. As soon as I try to load the form with the containing code I get a NotSupportedException that tells me "Event MouseUp is not valid on this ActiveX control." on the MultiStateData line at the bottom.

```
Public Const MaxMultiState = 99
Structure typState
    Public Caption As String
    Public Alignment As Long
    Public Appearance As Long
    Public BackStyle As Long
    Public BackColor As Long
    Public BorderStyle As Long
    Public ForeColor As Long
    Public FontName As String
    Public FontSize As Long
    Public FontBold As Boolean
    Public FontUnderline As Boolean
    Public FontItalic As Boolean
    Public FontStrikethru As Boolean
    Public IOID As Long
End Structure
Structure typMultiState
    Public Enabled As Boolean
    Public ToCopy As Boolean
    Public ControlName As String
    Public GroupID As Long
    Public States As Long
    Public CurrentState As Long
    Public State() As typState
    Public CopyNum As Long
    Public Visibility As Long
End Structure
Public MultiStateData(MaxMultiState) As typMultiState
```

This is not an ActiveX control and I have never tried to make any sort of events for it. It's just a data structure. There's an additional 12k lines of code in this form that I obviously won't post, but I can't think of any part of that code that would be relevant anyway. All I'm ever doing is reading or writing to the data structure.

Essentially what this is is a storage container for properties for a custom control that I haven't created yet. There is an associated dictionary of labels by a different name which I am accessing by a common index. Other than using the same index to access the two, they have nothing in common. My first thought was that somehow the data structure was getting confused with this dictionary of labels, since those DO use event handlers, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Typing this out now, I realize that I may be able to just create the control now so I can get rid of the data structure, and hopefully the problem, but I'm not really ready to do that yet.

I've been stuck on this for days now and I'm starting to reach my limit. Any direction would help.

Comment: The VB.NET compiler auto-generates a lot of code so you don't have to write it yourself.  Like the code that creates that array, it probably lives in a Module.  And the event subscriptions that are necessary on event handlers that use the `Handles` keyword.  If that code fails then the debugger has a hard time showing the exact location of the error since it is auto-generated code.  You'll need to get ahead by finding that MouseUp event handler and remove it.  Dollars to donuts, it is one you wrote for a WebBrowser control.

Comment: @HansPassant - I feel like I've done a fairly extensive search of all files in the entire solution and come up with 22 MouseUp event handlers in the main form, none of which belong to MultiStateData. No other files seem to have any show up. Is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Start commenting out your `MouseUp` methods/events. When it doesn't fail you will find out where and then can find out why...

Comment: You must stop thinking it has anything to do with MultiStateData.  It is just where the debugger stopped, not finding a better place to stop.  The exception is caused by one of those 22 MouseUp event handlers.  You can narrow it down to an ActiveX control, like WebBrowser.  And of course highly likely that it was one you recently added.  If that doesn't help then commenting them out one by one is not going to take a day and guaranteed to eventually hit the troublemaker.

Comment: Thank you both so much. I finally found the problem. I had purchased some ActiveX controls years ago. In porting the program from VB6 it seems that these controls have gained events followed by the word "Event", MouseUpEvent, KeyDownEvent, etc. Apparently I'm supposed to use these now as opposed to the original. Thank you again. I'll remember not to get so fixed on the stop line next time.